# Замена специальных символов при создании XML на PHP

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Задача такая, при создании XML, в DOMDocument на php нужно заменить `&, ', ", >, <` Эти символы на `&amp, &apos,  &quot, &gt , &lt`

Я из заменяю например

```
str_replace(['&', '\'', '"', '>', '<'], ['&amp', '&apos',  '&quot', '&gt' , '&lt'], $text);
```

Но есть и стандартная функция `htmlspecialchars` ни суть.

Дело в том что `createElement` вызывает ошибку

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference quotБанные штучки&quot in E:\DEV\fixcom\test\class\XMLManager.php on line 104
```

Но этот XML для API одного приложения, и там сказанно заменять эти символы! Как сделать так что бы  DOMDocument их принял?

Приведу пример кода

```
$dom =  new DOMDocument( "1.0", "utf-8" );
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$root =  $dom->createElement('start');
$root->setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$company = $dom->createElement('company','company');
$model = $dom->createElement('model',   htmlspecialchars('"TEST"   &     <AAA>   \'BBB\'' ));
$root->appendChild($model);
$dom->appendChild( $root );
print_r($dom->saveXML());
```

На выходе:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<start xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <model>"TEST"   &amp;     &lt;AAA&gt;   'BBB'</model>
</start>
```

Ковычки не заменились. Ни двойные ни одинарные.

Answer (score 0):

HTML сущности должны заканчиваться на `;`, поэтому `createElement()` не видит их.
Лучше использовать `htmlspecialchars()`.

UPD:
`createElement()` не позволяет экранировать кавычки. Об этом [сказано в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.createelement).
Устанавливайте значение через `textContent`:

```
$model = $dom->createElement('model');
$model->textContent = $text;
```

Comment: Ок, сделал, теперь просто ничего не меняется! даже если у себя добавляю ; или htmlspecialchars. domDocument->saveXML() выдает документ так же с обычными ковычками и остальными символами!, даже если руками ему пишу  &apos всеравно обычный знак, как отключить это?

Comment: Результат выполнения `domDocument->saveXML()` вы смотрите в браузере или в текстовом редакторе?

Comment: В командной строке php main.php

Comment: Дополнил ответ.